# ContentDocumentLink filter not working- Trailhead Conference Management App

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, files, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink

Im facing below error:

Implementation restriction: ContentDocumentLink requires a filter by a single Id on ContentDocumentId or LinkedEntityId using the equals operator or multiple Id's using the IN operator.
PFB Code:

```
public class AttachmentController {    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void updatePicturePath(String recordId){
        system.debug('recId  '+ recordId);
        //In Lightning Experience, Attachments are stored in ContentDocuments
        try{ 
            ContentDocumentLink docLink =[SELECT ContentDocumentId
                                          FROM ContentDocumentLink
                                          WHERE LinkedEntityId = :recordId];

            //ContentVersion Id uniquely identifies the attachment
            ContentVersion ver = [SELECT Id FROM ContentVersion Where 
                                  ContentDocumentId = :docLink.ContentDocumentId];
            //Update the Picture_Path field with the url of the image
            Speaker__c speaker = [SELECT Id FROM Speaker__c WHERE Id = :recordId];
            speaker.Picture_Path__c = '/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/'+ ver.Id; 
            upsert speaker;
        }catch(Exception e){
            system.debug('In Catch block');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have multiple ContentDocumentLink related to the same recordId ?

Comment: I dont know much about content documentLink have not worked on it before.... im following the trailhead steps.

Comment: @Priya Can you please confirm if you are getting the value in `recordId` ?

Comment: No im not getting value ,its null

Comment: You need to make sure that you pass valid Id as a parameter to your method. Can you post the code from where you are calling this method ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is because you are getting null value in `recordId` parameter (As mentioned by you in your comment).

The solution for your problem is to make sure that you pass a valid `Id` parameter to your method from wherever it is being called.

**Salesforce SOQL ignores the where clause when you filter on required Lookup fields by null. And as LinkedEntityId is a required lookup field on ContentDocumentLink, and you are trying to filter it by `null`, it ignores the entire where clause which leads to no filter at all in SOQL and that leads to below error.**

> Implementation restriction: ContentDocumentLink requires a filter by a
>   single Id on ContentDocumentId or LinkedEntityId using the equals
>   operator or multiple Id's using the IN operator.

[SOQL ignores : WHERE RequiredLookup__c = null](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lEPMQA2) is the idea on community, you can promote it, although in your case LinkedEntityId should always have a value, just that you are not passing the parameter properly.

- You can't run a query without filters against `ContentDocumentLink`.
- You can't filter on `ContentDocument` fields if you're filtering by `ContentDocumentId`. You can only filter on ContentDocument fields if you're filtering by `LinkedEntityId`.
- You can't filter on the related object fields. For example, you can't filter on the properties of the account to which a file is linked. You can filter on the properties of the file, such as the title field.

You can find further help on `ContentDocumentLink` at [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm) link

Comment: Thanks a lot rechecking for  valid Id parameter to your method from wherever it is being called has solved an issue. Problem was i used setParam instead of setParams This caused not setting recordId properly as parameter to server side function. Thanks a lot.

Comment: That's great !!